# How do I remove duplicate Chromium extension: Unity Integration?

Tags: unity, chromium

I have installed preview release PPA of the Unity Web Apps feature in Ubuntu 12.04. It works with a few minor problems but I understand it is a preview and not perfect yet.

My problem is I seem to have duplicate extensions (different version numbers) resulting in getting two prompts when visiting a site that integrates with Unity.

How do I remove the duplicate? Or can I just delete the older extension in the Chromium settings menu?

[image: Screenshot of 2 versions of same webapp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem in just deleting the older version in Chrome's settings. Just go to `chrome://settings/extensions` and delete it.

Comment: I deleted the older version and had no problems afterwards. Thanks for the suggestion.